# How to efficiently re-compute the inverse of positive definite matrix when its i-th row and column are changed

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Given a positive definite matrix $A\in R^{n\times n}$ with its inverse $B$ and the Singular Value Decomposition $A=USU^T$. If I replace the $i-$th row and column of $A$ with a vector $x^T\in R^{1\times n}$ and $x\in R^n$ respectively, so that the new matrix $C$ is generated.

Here, assume that $C$ is still a positive definite matrix, then my question is that how can I efficiently calculate the inverse of $C$ with the results $B$ and $A=USU^T$?

Maybe we should also know some other calculation results about $A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a rank-2 update. Let $\mathbf a_i$ be the $i$-th column of $A$, $u=e_i$ (the $i$-th standard basis vector) and $v=x-\mathbf a_i-\frac{x_{ii}-a_{ii}}2e_i$. Then $C=A+uv^T+vu^T$. Hence you may apply [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) twice to obtain
$$
C^{-1}=A^{-1}
+A^{-1}\frac{avv^T-(1+b)(vu^T+uv^T)+cuu^T}{(1+b)^2-ac}A^{-1},
$$
where $a=u^TA^{-1}u,\ b=u^TA^{-1}u$ and $c=v^TA^{-1}v$.